# How can I confirm application installation from Facebook ads,

Tags: java, facebook, api

What's the way to know if the latest app installations are from Facebook ads? I'd like to know exactly which devices are installed from which ads, so that I can do better advertising analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some questions to the problem，Recently, we have put some advertisements on Facebook. I want to know which applications are installed from facebook ads in order to better analyze the ads, not just the number of installations. Is there any way to get this information?